# Magento 2 Backend are very slow

Tags: magento2, database, linux

Please help me with issue. My main problem is that mysql are very slow. When i try create products in my CMS, it take mutch time. Example - create product take 4 min, delete product - 12 min.

I use CMS Magento 2.2 CE (community edition). Also there is 145 000 of products. Before we add products all was fine. Create product take about 5 sec, delete product about 5-10 sec.

Here is my system ​​​​​​​

```
Ubuntu 14 x64, Linux kernel 3.13, 16 cpu, SSD, 48 GB RAM
Magento 2.2 CE
Percona MySQL server 5.6 - here is config - https://pastebin.com/TVu1Ed7c
Varnish server 4.1
PHP 7.0.22
Nginx 1.12
Redis Server 4.0.2
```

I try run some profiling tests of magento and mysql

```
Here is slow log results - https://pastebin.com/kbFw0F28
Here is example of mysql request that are very slow - https://pastebin.com/mi656h2h
```

When i run mysqltuner.pl it show me that everything is OK. Also if there is 60 real users on my site i see mysql process takes very high load cpu. As example i have site on same CMS with 100 products and lower server< and it take about 500 users and feels ok.

So help me please with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: It's quite a lot for magento CE. Did you thought about EE? Or about using postgre sql?

Comment: check if you have any extra extensions related to product properties.

Comment: we try disable all external extensions, and it not help.